# SQL Query where a field will be default 0, or 1 When the category is Null or equal to the most servere id for the group

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following SQL Statement,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Mem.MemberID, Mem.LastName + ', ' + Mem.FirstName AS Name, 
    MIN(MD.DiagnosisID) OVER(PARTITION BY  Mem.MemberID) AS 'Most Severe Diagnosis'
    ,MIN(Diag.DiagnosisDescription) OVER(PARTITION BY  Mem.MemberID) AS 'Most Severe Diagnosis Description'
    ,dc.DiagnosisCategoryID, dc.CategoryDescription, dc.CategoryScore,
    MIN(ISNULL(DC.DiagnosisCategoryID,1)) OVER(PARTITION BY  Mem.MemberID) AS 'Most Severe Category'
FROM 
    Member AS Mem
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    MemberDiagnosis AS MD ON Mem.MemberID = MD.MemberID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Diagnosis AS Diag ON MD.DiagnosisID = Diag.DiagnosisID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DiagnosisCategoryMap AS Map ON Map.DiagnosisID = Diag.DiagnosisID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DiagnosisCategory AS DC ON DC.DiagnosisCategoryID = Map.DiagnosisCategoryID
ORDER BY Name
```

That returns the following table,

```
ID|NAME       |MOST SEVERE DIAG|DIAG DESCPTION |CatId|Cat DESC  |SCORE|Is Most Severe|
--+-----------+----------------+---------------+-----+----------+-----+--------------+
2 |Smith, Jack|NULL            |NULL           |NULL |NULL      |NULL |1             |
1 |Smith, John|2               |Test Diagnosis2|2    |Category B|20   |2             |
1 |Smith, John|2               |Test Diagnosis2|3    |Category C|30   |2             |
3 |Smyth, Will|3               |Test Diagnosis3|3    |Category C|30   |3             |
--+-----------+----------------+---------------+-----+----------+-----+--------------+
```

In Column 'Is Most Severe', how can I set it default to 0, or 1 if the CatId Is the most servere or null. So in the above table, the last column would have the data; 1 1 0 1.

Comment: What you need is a case statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Mem.MemberID,
    Mem.LastName + ', ' + Mem.FirstName AS Name, 
    MIN(MD.DiagnosisID) OVER(PARTITION BY Mem.MemberID) AS 'Most Severe Diagnosis',
    MIN(Diag.DiagnosisDescription) OVER(PARTITION BY Mem.MemberID) AS 'Most Severe Diagnosis Description',
    dc.DiagnosisCategoryID,
    dc.CategoryDescription,
    dc.CategoryScore,
    CASE WHEN dc.DiagnosisCategoryID = MIN(MD.DiagnosisID) OVER(PARTITION BY Mem.MemberID) OR
        dc.DiagnosisCategoryID IS NULL
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Is Most Severe'
FROM 
    Member AS Mem
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    MemberDiagnosis AS MD ON Mem.MemberID = MD.MemberID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Diagnosis AS Diag ON MD.DiagnosisID = Diag.DiagnosisID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DiagnosisCategoryMap AS Map ON Map.DiagnosisID = Diag.DiagnosisID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DiagnosisCategory AS DC ON DC.DiagnosisCategoryID = Map.DiagnosisCategoryID
ORDER BY
    Name;
```

Comment: That is exactly it. Thank you, was trying If Else but it wasn't working like i expected.